# Find values of $a$ in $\{2,3,\dots ,9999\}$ such that $a^2-a$ is divisible by 10000.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Today was my entrance test for BSc.(Hons.) in that there was a question which I was unable to solve. I'm asking this question here because I think that the question was wrong(**most probably I'm wrong**).

**Question**

Show that there are exactly 2 value of $a$ in $\{2,3,\dots ,9999\}$ such that $a^2-a$ is divisible by 10000.Find these two values.

I tried to solve this problem for 30 mins but I was unable to solve this. Finally I was frustrated and wrote that there is no value of $a$ in the given interval such that $a^2-a$ is divisible by 10000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that $10000=10^4=5^4\times 2^4$. Next,

$$10^4\mid a^2-a\iff a^2-a\equiv 0\pmod{10^4}\implies a(a-1)\equiv 0\pmod{10^4}$$

Since the two integers $a$ and $(a-1)$ are consecutive integers, they are coprime (can be easily shown by the Euclidean Algorithm).

So, you should have one of the two cases:

$$a(a-1)\equiv 0\pmod{10^4}\implies\begin{cases}a\equiv 0\pmod{2^4}~\land~a-1\equiv 0\pmod{5^4}\\ a\equiv 0\pmod{5^4}~\land~a-1\equiv 0\pmod{2^4}\end{cases}$$

These are quite easily solvable but the no-brainer method is to use Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) to solve the two cases. Each case has a unique solution and hence, you get 2 solutions.

Comment: [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Consecutive_Integers_are_Coprime) is a link for the proof of the theorem in case you need it.

Comment: I'll leave the work of finding the two values to the OP.

Comment: **Note:** There are two more cases which are $a\equiv 0\pmod{10^4}$ and $a\equiv 1\pmod{10^4}$ but we're not considering those two cases since the solution set of those two cases have no elements that fall in the given set of values of $a$ in the OP's question.

Comment: I assume you missed my stalking, here's one [similar question](https://brilliant.org/problems/its-like-youre-my-mirror-my-mirror-staring-back-at/).

Comment: @GohP.iHan, cool, thanks for the link. :D

Answer (score 3):

You want either $$\begin{align}a&\equiv 1\pmod {625}\\a&\equiv 0\pmod{16}\end{align}$$

or:

$$\begin{align}a&\equiv 0\pmod {625}\\a&\equiv 1\pmod{16}\end{align}$$

Solve these with Chinese Remainder Theorem.

(There are two more solutions, but they are essentially $a\equiv 0,1\pmod{10000}$, which are outside the range allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: factorising gives $a^2-a=a(a-1)$ which is a product of two consecutive integers $a$ and $a-1$.

Comment: Sir I have also done this but what next? Please more hints.

Comment: You should write in the question what you have tried already!

Answer (score 1):

To solve $x^2-x\equiv 0 \pmod{2^4 5^4}$, we can use the Chinese remainder theorem to combine solutions to $x^2-x\equiv 0 \pmod{2^4}$ and $x^2-x\equiv 0 \pmod{5^4}$.

Now, it is easy to see that $x=0$ and $x=1$ solve both these equations, and so we get solutions to the original equation by solving each of the following congruences:

$$x\equiv 0 \pmod{2^4},\qquad x\equiv 0 \pmod{5^4}.$$ 
$$x\equiv 1 \pmod{2^4},\qquad x\equiv 1 \pmod{5^4}.$$
$$x\equiv 0 \pmod{2^4},\qquad x\equiv 1 \pmod{5^4}.$$
$$x\equiv 1 \pmod{2^4},\qquad x\equiv 0 \pmod{5^4}.$$

However, because $\mathbb{Z}/2^4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/5^4 \mathbb Z$ are not fields, we do not necessarily know that there are only two solutions to the quadratic equation $x^2-x=0$ over these rings.  If we wish to show that the above congruence yield the only solutions, we need to be slightly more careful.

Suppose that $x(x-1)$ were divisible by $2^4$.  Since $x$ and $x-1$ are necessarily coprime, it is impossible that both of them contribute factors of $2$ to the product, and so either $2^4|x$ or $2^4|x-1$.    The same argument works with $2^4$ replaced with $5^4$.  Therefore, the congruence above yield the only solutions, and all that is left is for us to compute them.  The first two are solved by $x=0$ and $x=1$ respectively.  The last two can be solved by using the euclidean algorithm.